# Keras' `model.fit_generator()` returns different results than `model.fit()`

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I need to use model.fit_generator() to avoid feeding large amount of data into RAM memory. However, the behaviour when using model.fit_generator() is completely different than model.fit().

```
def generator(inputs, targets,batch_size=128,window=300):

    num_of_steps = int((len(inputs)-window+1) / batch_size)# - 1
    indexes=list(range(num_of_steps))

    np.random.shuffle(indexes)


    while True:
        for ei, e in enumerate(indexes):
          offset = e * batch_size

          mainpart = inputs
          meterpart = targets
          mainpart = np.array(mainpart)
          indexer = np.arange(window)[None, :] + np.arange(len(mainpart) window+1)[offset:offset + batch_size, None]

          mainpart = mainpart[indexer]
          meterpart = meterpart[indexer]

          X = np.reshape(mainpart, (batch_size, window, 1))
          Y = np.reshape(meterpart, (batch_size,window))

          yield X,Y


t = generator(train_x[0], train_y[0])
model.fit_generator(t, 
                    steps_per_epoch = int((len(train_x[0])-window+1) / batch_size), 
                    epochs=num_epochs)
```

So the code above behaves as shown below

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4mwm.png)

```
 indexer = np.arange(params['window_size'])[None, :] + np.arange(len(train_x[0])-params['window_size']+1)[:, None]
 x = train_x[0][indexer]
 y = train_y[0][indexer]

 x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0],params['window_size'],1))
 y = np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0],params['window_size']))

 model.fit(x, y, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
```

while model.fit() behaves in this way

[image]

Please, anyone can help on this?